# Is it possible to figure out which if statements are being fufilled in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a lot of if statements throughout my code and was wondering if there is anyway in Matlab to see which if statements are being used when I run my code. I know I could put variables throughout my code and see which ones are being triggered, but I was wondering if there is an easier way. Maybe a built in MATLAB function or something.

Thanks

Comment: You could step through your code in debug mode? Otherwise you can log to a text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `profile viewer` in the command line of matlab and execute your code from there. There you can see in the profile report how many times each line is called as well as how long it takes executing the line of code.

More information:

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/profile.html

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html

Answer (score 1):

To answer precesely to your question, there is a command to log every line the execution is going through. And if you're familiar with unix-like platform, it is the same command: `echo`. See the [Matlab help of `echo`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/echo.html) to see how you can use it. For example, `echo on all` sets echoing on for all function files.

Besides that, I advise you two things better than analysing the output of echoing a whole script:

- look at every warning in the code editor, and apply meaningful corrections.
- use the profiler of matlab, as stated in the [answer from EJG89](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866918/1507014), it is indeed a powerful tool!